# Inline list with nested ul on slide toggle forces li to display as block item

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, css

Hi I have an ul list which contains input with checkboxes I am using to create a filter system. I am hiding the nested uls with jquery and using slide toggle to un hide them. I have the main uls list inline but when I slide toggle they are forced as block items. I want them to stay in line but I can't seem to force them.

My schema is as so:

```
<ul class="top-category">
    <li class="expandable closed">Filter by: Blog Categories <span class="icon-arrow-down3"></span>

        <ul class="child-category">
            <li class="expandable closed">  <span><input type="checkbox" id="tag_278" name="blog_categories[]" class="custom-checkbox" value="Tech" data-name="Tech"/>Tech</span></li>
             <li class="expandable closed"> <span><input type="checkbox" id="tag_278" name="blog_categories[]" class="custom-checkbox" value="Tech" data-name="Tech"/>Asset Production</span></li>
              <li class="expandable closed">    <span><input type="checkbox" id="tag_278" name="blog_categories[]" class="custom-checkbox" value="Tech" data-name="Tech"/>Design</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expandable closed">Filter by: Staff <span class="icon-arrow-down3"></span>

        <ul class="child-category">
            <li class="expandable closed">  <span><input type="checkbox" id="tag_283" name="staff[]" class="custom-checkbox" value="Staff One" data-name="Staff One"/>Staff One</span></li>
            <li class="expandable closed">  <span><input type="checkbox" id="tag_283" name="staff[]" class="custom-checkbox" value="Staff One" data-name="Staff One"/>Staff Memeber Two</span></li>
            <li class="expandable closed">  <span><input type="checkbox" id="tag_283" name="staff[]" class="custom-checkbox" value="Staff One" data-name="Staff One"/>Staff Memeber THree</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS is as so:

```
ul.top-category {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul.top-category li.expandable {
    display:inline;
}
```

and I have jQuery which takes care of the toggling :

```
// bind focus and blur of checkboxes and navigation keys
$('li.expandable').each(
    function (i, li) {
        li = $(li);
        li.find('input')
            .focus(function () {
                $('.active').removeClass('active'); 
                li.toggleClass('active');})
            .blur(function () {
                li.toggleClass('active');})
            .on('keyup', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == '40') { // down
                    li.next('li.expandable').find('input').focus()
                } else if (e.keyCode == '38') { // up
                    li.prev('li.expandable').find('input').focus()
                }})
})

// fold all those with class closed
$('li.expandable.closed').children('ul').hide()

// li click
$('li.expandable').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $li = $(this);
    //$li.find('input').focus()
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $li.addClass('active');
    $li.children('ul').slideToggle('fast').toggleClass('open');
    if (e.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
        var cbx = $li.children('input');
        cbx.prop('checked', !cbx.prop("checked"))
    }
});

// set focus to first checkbox
$('li.expandable > input').first().focus()
```

But when I toggle the main li's in the ul.top-category are no logger inline. Does anyone know of a fix or perhaps a way I can change the layout to be better?

I have a JSFiddle to demo how this responds here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pbcb59cx/)

Comment: You can force them in CSS using !important which is not a good practice `li.active ul.open {display: inline !important}`

Comment: Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/pbcb59cx/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pbcb59cx/3/)

```
ul.top-category {
display:inline-block;
float: left;
list-style-type:none;
position: relative;
}
ul.top-category li.expandable {
display:inline;
}

ul.child-category {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 0;
}
```